# Is it in this case still safe to use Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security, mac

My Macbook Air is to old to use the newer versions of Tor. Is it in this case still safe to use the older Tor version, or do I really have to buy a new computer to use Tor safely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not safe to use old versions of Tor Browser or any other internet connected software.

This is **explicitly what it says in the out-of-date version warnings** so I'm not sure why you're asking here again as if somehow the warnings were just a joke or something.

It's a shame that your operating system vendor likes to price gouge so much, you might be able to opt to run an operating system like [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) to get around the restrictions put in place by Apple.

Comment: where can I find the out-of-date version warnings (German Version)?    Sorry - I'm  new in the Tor world never really used the old Version

Comment: It should appear when Tor Browser starts and discovers that a new version has been released.

Comment: When Tor Browser starts it doesent show any warnings else than telling me to download the newer verion and that the Browser is not up-to-date. No warnings about that the older vorsion is not "safe".

Comment: hmmm I can't even get it to run an out of date version without manually disabling automatic updates (where it notes explicitly that doing so is a security risk), how are you getting it to not automatically update?

Comment: I am quite an amateur on anything that has to do with computers - I might have disabled "automatic updates" manualy at some point when the Version was still uptodate (just checked and "automatic Updates" where disabled...)

Comment: So, yeah, enable them and just use automatic updates. Tor is based off of the "ESR" which means 99% of the time, updates contain important security fixes.

Comment: Ok - this is helpfull! I will try out "Tales" as well.